# What does "civilized system" mean in Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Jabba warns Han Solo:

> Jabba: Okay, 15%. But if you fail me again...I'll put a price on your
> head so big... you won't be able to go near a **civilized system**.

What does "civilized system" mean in Star Wars universe?

Comment: It’s more what Jabba means rather than what it means in Star Wars.  Presumably any world with any sort of civilization that is known within the Empire or to the Hutts and with a population intelligent enough to understand Jabba’s price on Han.

Comment: We are now at the point in the star wars extended universe where even adjectives are getting backstories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He was possibly referring to the **Convention of Civilized Systems**, something similar to the *Bill Of Rights* that determined a species sentience. It was referred during the **Clone Wars** series in Season 1 Episode 15.

> It is obvious these creatures are not covered by the Convention of Civilized Systems. The Jedi Council has no say in the matter."
> ―Chairman Chi Cho, on the Talz

Although that might be the in-universe explanation, I believe that the real world explanation is the exact opposite, they took Jabba's words and built on top of it.

Comment: that's a deep cut and retcon but +1 for an obscure reference